# Present perfect confusion

Tags: present-perfect

I would like to appreciate the team for the support.

**For present perfect,** can I say:

> "I have come, today"

or

> "I come today"

**For past simple:**

> "I come two days ago"

or

> "I came two days ago"

Comment: I have edited out your second question because 1) one question at a time please, 2) It is an incorrect assumption, it **is** "two bedrooms"

Comment: @JanDoggen Not if it's a *two-bedroom apartment* …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I have come today.(present perfect)**
>   right.
>
> **I come today(simple present** is not natural
>
> **I come two days ago**( wrong) simple present
>
> **I came two days ago**( simple past)  right.

Comment: I got it , many thanks for all !